# Sorting users through relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5

i want to sort the users through voornaam(firstname). but im getting the data via a relation.

How do i make my query so that, the relation users are sorted by firstname by alphabet

my function:

```
public function sortfirstname($id) {
    $ingeschrevenspelers = UserToernooi::with('users')->where('toernooiid', '=', $id)->get()->all();
 //This query ^^


    $toernooi = Toernooi::findOrFail($id);

    dd($ingeschrevenspelers);
    return view('adminfeatures.generatespelerslijst', compact('ingeschrevenspelers', 'toernooi'));
}
```

What i want to sort
[image]

any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fire **all()** function at the end thus obtaining a **Collection** instance of result

```
//query without the all function
$ingeschrevenspelers = UserToernooi::with('users')->where('toernooiid', '=', $id)->get();

//
$ingeschrevenspelers = $ingeschrevenspelers->sortBy('users.firstname');
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing code in your own language doesn't make it very easy for other developers to understand your code.

That being said, you can try the `orderBy()` method on your relationship

In your model where you define the relationship:

```
public function relationship() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SomeClass::class)->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [Jordy Groote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5935647/jordy-groote)'s answer if you do not want to modify the Model class itself, you can query it with a closure.

```
$ingeschrevenspelers = UserToernooi::with(['users' => function($q) {  
    $q->orderBy('voornaam', 'asc');
}])->where('toernooiid', '=', $id)->get()->all();
```

**Reference**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

*Sidenote: I don't think you need a `->all()` when you already did a `->get()`*

Comment: Thanks this should work also, thank you for helping. but Max was first to answer so his answer is checked as best answer.

Comment: lol. Max was the last to answer. But its cool. Max's answer seem simpler if it gives your expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
$ingeschrevenspelers = UserToernooi::with(['users' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('voornaam', 'asc');
}])->where('toernooiid', '=', $id)->get()->all();
```

Comment: Thanks this should work also, thank you for helping. but Max was first to answer so his answer is checked as best answer.